# PyCharm console not displaying properly

Tags: pycharm

I am setting up PyCharm on my computer, and the interactive console seems to be having trouble displaying output results.  For example, when I try to display

> command?

I get a big messy string in response instead of formatted output.

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
In[2]: import numpy as np
In[3]: np.sum?
{'text/plain': 'Signature: np.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)\nDocstring:\nSum of array elements over a given axis.\n\nParameters\n----------\na : array_like\n    Elements to sum.\naxis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional\n    Axis or axes along which a sum is performed.  The default,\n    axis=None, will sum all of the elements of the input array.  If\n    axis is negative it counts from the last to the first axis.\n\n    .. versionadded:: 1.7.0\n\n    If axis is a tuple of ints, a sum is performed on all of the axes\n    specified in the tuple instead of a single axis or all the axes as\n    before.\ndtype : dtype, optional\n    The type of the returned array and of the accumulator in which the\n    elements are summed.  The dtype of `a` is used by default unless `a`\n    has an integer dtype of less precision than the default platform\n    integer.  In that case, if `a` is signed then the platform integer\n    is used while if `a` is unsigned then an unsigned integer of the\n    same precision as the platform integer is used.\nout : ndarray, optional\n    Alternative output array in which to place the result. It must have\n    the same shape as the expected output, but the type of the output\n    values will be cast if necessary.\nkeepdims : bool, optional\n    If this is set to True, the axes which are reduced are left in the\n    result as dimensions with size one. With this option, the result\n    will broadcast correctly against the input array.\n\nReturns\n-------\nsum_along_axis : ndarray\n    An array with the same shape as `a`, with the specified\n    axis removed.   If `a` is a 0-d array, or if `axis` is None, a scalar\n    is returned.  If an output array is specified, a reference to\n    `out` is returned.\n\nSee Also\n--------\nndarray.sum : Equivalent method.\n\ncumsum : Cumulative sum of array elements.\n\ntrapz : Integration of array values using the composite trapezoidal rule.\n\nmean, average\n\nNotes\n-----\nArithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is\nraised on overflow.\n\nThe sum of an empty array is the neutral element 0:\n\n>>> np.sum([])\n0.0\n\nExamples\n--------\n>>> np.sum([0.5, 1.5])\n2.0\n>>> np.sum([0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 1.5], dtype=np.int32)\n1\n>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]])\n6\n>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=0)\narray([0, 6])\n>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)\narray([1, 5])\n\nIf the accumulator is too small, overflow occurs:\n\n>>> np.ones(128, dtype=np.int8).sum(dtype=np.int8)\n-128\nFile:      ~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py\nType:      function\n'}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Using PyCharm CE 2016.3.1 on MacOS 10.12.2, using Python 3.5.2 Anaconda as my interpreter.

Comment: It would be better to paste in the text from the console rather than a screen shot.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, updated.